# Finding residue from a Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that you can calculate the residue of a Laurent Series by looking at the coefficient of the z^-1 term ie

eg for this series

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/3/9/f3948f08f460e5569f52efdcbd82021b.png

the coeffiecient is 2, hence the residue is 2

My question is when we have a series that does not contain a term with z^-1, do we say the residue is 0 or doesnt exist ?

Comment: If there is a pole at $z_0$ then the residue is the coefficient of the $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ term which means it would be a 0 if it is not there. If there isn't a pole then there is no residue.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=poles+of+1%2F%28z-2%29%5E2 This is a link to a function where it has a pole of order 2 but it has a zero residue!

Comment: ah I understand know , the expansion of the series has no z^-1 term so we say the residue is 0 . http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laurent+series+of+1%2F%28z-2%29^2

Is the singular point of the function z=2

Comment: Are Singular Points and Poles the same thing ?

Comment: Well there are different kinds of isolated singularities, for instance if you had the function $f(z) = sin(z)/z$ we would have a removable singularity since the function $|f(z)|$ is bounded as $z\to 0$ since we know its limit goes to 1. There is also essential singularities, which I personally don't know much about.

Comment: So for Example
for cos(z-3)/(z-3)
is z=3 a singular point, with residue being 1 ?
and residue =1 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent+expansion+at+z%3D3+of+cos%28z-3%29%2F%28z-3%29

Comment: Yeah at $z = 3$ we have a pole of order 1, so then its residue is 1. Remember you may not always have the laurent expansion in front of you, it is really good for you to learn how to just calculate the residue via understanding the connection between poles, its order and its residue.